# Correct term for stacked / super-justified / variable height text

Tags: typography, terminology, style-identification

Meaning like this, where there's a fixed width, and every line is scaled maintaining its aspect ratio to meet the width - **including scaling the height** (unlike regular justified text).

There might be tweaks to the tracking and kerning, but they're not the core feature of the style, which is the changing text size:

[image]

---

Woah! While finding examples I just noticed we have an almost-identical question already:

[image]

[What is the name for making words equal in length?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/what-is-the-name-for-making-words-equal-in-length)

But those answers don't give a name for this *style*, they're just typographic terms, some of which may be used in creating this style, but none of which *are* this style.

**Is there a name for this style**, where the size (width and height) is adjusted to make each line equal in width and to bring out certain words?

It's not "justifying", because that doesn't involve changing the **size** of text, that only changes the letter spacing or occasionally width. It never changes the height. It's not "[typesetting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting)", which is setting type. 99% of the work of typesetters is not in this style.

Comment: I don't think there's a name specifically. They same way there's not really a specific name for using oversized quote marks in a callout.

Comment: I quite like the term *super-justified* for it, but in practice I think *justified* is the most common description

Comment: I have heard people call it "justified", and then people have got confused because they think they mean regular-justified when actually they mean this.

Comment: I've used and heard "justified" often for these types of things. It's merely justified *words* as opposed to paragraphs or sentences.

Comment: While it *is* justified text, justification typically has nothing to do with *scaling* text so it's not a great term. The best I could fine in terms of anything semi-official is the term *slab text* as answered here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46861/306

Comment: As for the term 'justified' there are variations: 1) left-justified (only left side is aligned) 2) right-justified (only right side is aligned) and 3) justified *or* force-justified (both-sides aligned). Again, none of these terms refer to changing the size of type on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: Duplicates! Duplicates everywhere! :-) Thanks DA01, slab is good, risks confusion with slab-serif, I like the idea of coining "slab justified"... also found this related typophile article http://www.typophile.com/node/65513 and hell, there's even a jQuery plugin http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say **slab-justified text**.

This is a style that combines the two ideas of slab text and text justification, which are also the most commonly used (but potentially misleading) existing names. Rather than using a name that only covers half of the idea, let's combine them.

- Like **[Justified](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19499/3327)** text, this is a method of aligning text resulting in lines having equal widths. Just calling it "justified", however, invites confusion with conventional text justification, which only adjusts tracking or width (not text size or height), and is used very differently giving a very different aesthetic effect.
- Like **[slab text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/46861/306)**, this uses text of different sizes to create a blocky aesthetic effect where the text is the eye-catching feature. Just calling it "slab text", however, does not specify *equal* widths, and may sound like a style of typeface (like [slab serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_serif)) rather that a type of text alignment or arrangement.

Anyone familiar with either the history of the term "slab text" or the modern (mis-) use of "justified" will know what you mean. Anyone who isn't will imagine a slab of text with a blocky aesthetic where every line has equal length: which is pretty much what this is.

Crucially, it doesn't invite misunderstandings. It wouldn't leave someone confident they know what you mean when actually they're thinking of something else entirely.

It also gives the most relevant search results (including image search) of anything I've tried, including handy resources like [this jQuery plugin](http://freqdec.github.io/slabText/).