# How to Adjust text of different sizes in single alignment in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment

Im fairly new to illustrator, I was wondering if there was an easier way of recreating this effect, I use it a lot and to be fair i feel that almost every software should have an easier way of doing this. Unfortunately I don't know what this style of text alignment is even called. I would really love some help on this, Thanks[image]

Comment: Hi Shravan, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. This is called 'slab text', as you can see in [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/what-is-the-name-for-making-words-equal-in-length). There is no easy way to do this in Illustrator. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks for the name, I'm really grateful, gives me something to work with :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a script that does that, type all your lines in separate Point Text frames, select them all, then run the script. The script will ask you for the width of the Block and the spacing between lines, then it'll outline a copy of each frame, size and position accordingly.

[textBlock.jsx](http://aiscripts.com/text-block/)

Comment: Oh that's very helpful, I'll let you know how it goes... thanks... :)