# Making Text Fit in a Box in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, page-layout

I'm looking at how to design a graphic in Photoshop so that whether it has 2 words, 5 words, etc. they all fit within the same width of a box.

Here's an example: [image]

How can I do this without distorting the text by stretching, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried justified paragraph?

Comment: Related: [What is the name for making words equal in length?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/what-is-the-name-for-making-words-equal-in-length) and [What is this “justified” text technique called?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46855/what-is-this-justified-text-technique-called)

Answer (score 2):

1) Write eacher sentence in seperate layers

2) Align them left

3) Resize them until they have same width

4) If required, change font size, letter spacing too.